# iPhone - Is it possible to hide native scrollbar in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I would like to hide the native scrollbar / scroller that appears when you are scrolling a UIWebView, but still keep the scrolling functionality intact. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

William

Comment: For anyone working on iOS 5.0 and above.
Consider the newer answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems this question needs **an updated answer**:

You can directly access the scroll view associated with the web view. (read-only)
in iOS 5.0 an above.
I don't think developers should be supporting anything prior to iOS 5.0 unless in exceptional circumstances.

**From the Apple developer docs.**

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView
Discussion
Your application can access the scroll view if it wants to customize the scrolling behavior of the web view.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
UIWebView.h
```

Now you can **directly write** something like this:

```
webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

**No need to go to the subviews of the webView.**

Comment: `webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false` worked for me in SWIFT

Answer (score 11):

`UIWebView` doesn't inherit directly from `UIScrollView`, but you may be able to use `UIScrollView` properties on the `UIWebView` subview:

```
[(UIScrollView*)[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[(UIScrollView*)[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

No idea if this is acceptable, but it builds okay and I think it should work. Please report back if this works for you.

Also consider filing a feature request to Apple at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) to add this property to a future `UIWebView` implementation.

Comment: This code works in iOS 4.0 - 5.0, but not in iOS 3.1.3. In iOS 4.0-5.0 `[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0]` returns instance of _UIWebViewScrollView, which can be casted to UIScrollView, but in iOS 3.1.3 it returns instance of UIScroller, which failed to cast to UIScrollView.

Comment: Alex Reynolds, Although I have provided an answer but since your answer is at the top.
Could you update it.
in iOS 5.0 and above.
scrollView of the webview can be accessed as a readonly property.

Answer (score 5):

Do it in that way:

```
for (id subview in self.myWebView.subviews) {
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO; 
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;    
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift :

```
    webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for swift solution then below is the code for **swift 3.0**

```
yourWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
yourWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score -1):

There's seems to be the beginning of an answer here :

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1781730

If you disable user interaction, this seems to remove the scrollbar (this may be ok if the web page you display does not exceed the screen height).

A kind of javascript hack seems to be described also but I'm not mastering it :/ (you need to have access to the web page you try to display however, and this may not be your case....)